# Why ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException for 2D Array and NPE for 1D array

Tags: java, arrays, exception, indexoutofboundsexception

Please help me to understand why below code throws ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

```
Integer[][] arr1 = { { 1, 2, 3 }, { null }, { 7, 8, 9 } };
System.out.println("value = " + arr1[1][1].intValue());
```

Similar code when executed for single dimensional array throws NullPointerException.

```
Integer[] arr2 = { new Integer(1) , null , new Integer(2) };
System.out.println("value = " + arr2[1].intValue());
```

In my understanding I should get NPE for both 1D and 2D array.

Comment: In the first case, `arr1[1]` is `{null}`, an array with **one** element. So `arr1[1][1]` is an index error. In the second case, `arr2[1]` is null, so trying to call a method on it gives an NPE.

Comment: If you try to access the null element with `arr1[1][0]`, then you will get the NPE.

Comment: @GriffeyDog Just to clarify, *accessing* `null` via `arr1[1][0]` wouldn't cause `NPE`. But *after* we access it successfully `arr1[1][0].intValue()` will become `null.intValue()` and that *call* would throw NPE.

Comment: @Pshemo That's what I intended with my comment, accessing the `intValue` method on that element. My point was that the `null` element resides at index 0, not 1.

Answer (score 0):

It's because the array at index `1` (`arr1[1]`) is a valid array with 1 `null` in it. If you checked `arr1[1][0]` it would return `null` without an exception. You're getting an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` because it's a valid array but ends at index `0`.

If you switched the code to:

```
Integer[][] arr1 = { { 1, 2, 3 }, null, { 7, 8, 9 } };
```

in which index `arr1[1]` is actually `null` (instead of an array with `null` in it), then you would get a `NullPointerException`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to produce a NullPointerException in the first case, you have to replace:

```
Integer[][] arr1 = { { 1, 2, 3 }, { null }, { 7, 8, 9 } };
System.out.println("value = " + arr1[1][1].intValue());
```

with:

```
Integer[][] arr1 = { { 1, 2, 3 }, { null, null }, { 7, 8, 9 } };
System.out.println("value = " + arr1[1][1].intValue());
```

to make the individual array1 element `arr1[1][1]` null.

Otherwise `arr1[1][1]` is not instantiated and you get `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`.